# Complexity class: machine speed is doubled, how larger a size that could be solved in x amount of time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

My CS course for Data Structures Analysis is going over complexity classes right now. My homework is to find out how much more problems that can be solved with the same amount of time given:

a.) Complexity class

b.) Problem size

c.) The time it took for current machine to solve for that problem size previously

d.) **The Machine has doubled in speed**

The first question has a complexity class of O(log base 2 of N), at 10^6 size, which could be solved in 1 second (for current computer). How do I begin to figure out how much more can be solved from this? I know how to solve a class if it increased by a factor of some number, but not this!

Anything that will help me understand how to solve this problem will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic complexity denotes that for your task:

```
Old set, on slow machine:
K * Log(N) = 1 (seconds)
New set, fast machine:
K * Log(M) = 1
New set, slow machine: (twice as slow)
K * Log(M) = 2
```

Now you can compare

```
2 * K * Log(N) = K * Log(M)
Log(M) = 2 * Log(N) = Log(N^2)
M = N^2
```

So the size of set, solvable on faster machine in 1 second, is N squared, 10^12 in your case

Comment: Huh so you set how much faster the new set is compared to the old set. Isolate for m,  exponent law... Oh. Oh damn it, I get it now. ._. Thank you for the step by step!